# Change background of fixed header when scrolling past elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background-color

I'm trying to get the background-color of my fixed header to change upon scrolling over certain DIV sections on the page, similar to this:

http://www.adamrudzki.com/

The sections I'm using don't have a fixed height.

I've found this similar question [Change background-color while scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598570/change-background-color-while-scrolling)

( which uses this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cEvJk/18/ )

```
var t = $('#about').offset().top - 100;

$(document).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > t)
    {   
        $('header').css({"background-color":"green"});
    } 
});
```

But I'm unable to get the effect to repeat for all sections.

Comment: is `header` the `<header>` tag or a class?

Comment: In the [example](http://www.adamrudzki.com/) you give The header is actually has a transparent background.

Comment: Can you show your fiddle or any demo link where you are working currently?

Comment: Hi Dhiraj Shah, I have uploaded an example of the site so far to

http://www.jiraff.co.uk/demo/demo.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this :

```
var t = $('#about').offset().top - 100;
var t1 = $('#work').offset().top - 100;

$(document).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > t1) {   
        $('header').css({"background-color":"blue"});
    } else if($(this).scrollTop() > t) {   
        $('header').css({"background-color":"green"});
    } else {
        $('header').css({"background-color":"#520833"});
    }
});
```

And so on with `var  t2 = ...`.

Don't forget to put higher values on top of the `if`'s

Comment: This worked fantastically. Thank you very much for your help Nathan P!

Comment: Pleased to help you :)

Comment: I've noticed that the way I have set it up can make it perform slightly differently if the window is resized - Do you know if there's anything that could be done to make this script refresh upon browser resize?

Comment: @DaleIrwin See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599288/cross-browser-window-resize-event-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 6):

You could simplify things a bit by using [jQuery's .each() method](https://api.jquery.com/each/) like this:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/cEvJk/32/)**

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('.sect').each(function () {
        var w = $(window).scrollTop();
        var t = $(this).offset().top - 100;
        if (w > t) {
            $('header').css({
                "background-color": $(this).css('background-color')
            });
        }
    });
});
```

From the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/each/#entry-longdesc):

> The .each() method is designed to make DOM looping constructs concise
>   and less error-prone. When called it iterates over the DOM elements
>   that are part of the jQuery object. Each time the callback runs, it is
>   passed the current loop iteration, beginning from 0. More importantly,
>   the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so
>   the keyword this refers to the element.

Comment: This is the way to do it man. Why would you want to hardcode the values like in the previous answers. Just imagine if you have more sections or when you add new sections, do you want to go back to your script and add more js? This is safe :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I came up with [**THIS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cEvJk/26/)

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var x = $(this).scrollTop(),
        home = $('#home'),
        about = $('#about'),
        work = $('#work'),
        contact = $('#contact');

    if (x >= home.offset().top && x < (home.offset().top + home.height())) {
        $('header').css("background-color", "red");
    }
    if (x >= about.offset().top && x < (about.offset().top + about.height())) {
        $('header').css("background-color", "green");
    }
    if (x >= work.offset().top && x < (work.offset().top + work.height())) {

        $('header').css("background-color", "blue");
    }
    if (x >= contact.offset().top && x < (contact.offset().top + contact.height())) {
        $('header').css("background-color", "orange");
    }
});
```